# Monitoring DFSR for a specific file

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a large template file (about 40-50Gb) within VMware. The Template file is created on a datastore that is replicated between 2 datacentres using DFSR.

I need to monitor the DFSR status in order that once a specific file has replicated, the script will go on to do some other bits and pieces.

```
$file = myfile.template
$timeout = new-timespan -minutes 5
start-sleep -seconds 5
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout) {
$DFSRStatus = get-dfsrstatus | where{$_.name -eq $file}
if ($DFSRStatus.something -eq 'ok') {
return
}
start-sleep -seconds 5
}
Exit
```

Unfortunately, I've not used the DFSR Module. I've tried adding a file to check the replication status, to see what happens when a file gets replicated. But even with creating a 1 Gb test file, I wasn't able to see what happens when the replication is in progress and when it was successful.

Hopefully someone with more experience in DFSR can highlight what the right syntax is to check DFSR for a specific file and what the correct 'success' event is.

Comment: You can try to use Get-DfsrBacklog : a little bit tricky of course if there is a lot of activity on your DFSR targets but if you don't have a lot of activity no backlog means the file is replicated. You can of course also just check directly on the target server if the file exists with test-path

Comment: @bluuf Testing for file exists vs a local path in DFSR with a file this big will not do, because the file will start existing when its replication *starts*, not ends. `Get-DFSRBacklog` seems to be the way to go here, but it can return a megaton of entries, and is VERY slow to execute even with a hundred. I used to parse `Get-DFSRBacklog -Verbose` as it first returns the count of the backlog in a verbose channel, although I only needed the DFSR health in form of no/low backlog.

Comment: You could perhaps check when the size of the file matches the size in source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:  Instead of trying to monitor DFSR, just check to see if the file is at the target location, and is the correct size and date when compared to the original.

Comment: So, you mean instead of calling DFSR - My loop should have something like:


`Compare-Object (ls Source\$file) (ls Dest\$file) -Property Name, Length`

Comment: Yes, exactly..  (Although I'd be a bit different)   
   
if you know the file names of each machine, and there is only two of them, then **Compare-object ** in a loop is a good choice,  

`$fileSource = "c:\boot.ini"   
 $fileDest = "\\127.0.0.1\c$\boot.ini"    
   
`    $results = compare-object -referenceobject $(get-content     $fileSource) -differenceobject $(get-content  $fileDest)     

Now, put this in a loop, and loop until the values are the same, checkiong what was returned into the $results variable.